# unique index is inserting rows with null column values instead of just rejecting them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sidekiq

I have a table `journal_entries` that I have placed a unique index on the `line_item_id` column.

```
 Column    |            Type             |                          Modifiers                           | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id           | integer                     | not null default nextval('journal_entries_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 line_item_id | integer                     |                                                              | plain    |              | 
 .....
 .....
Indexes:
    "journal_entries_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_journal_entries_on_line_item_id" UNIQUE, btree (line_item_id)
```

`line_item_id` is a nullable column but that shouldn't matter.

I'm noticing that instead of rejecting a new column when the `line_item_id` is a duplicate, the database inserts the row but with `line_item_id` as `null`

I've been trying to debug this for weeks using active record callbacks etc and I can't find an instance of this happening in the code. It seems to be the database acting on its own.

This process is typically happening in a Sidekiq server, could be something to do with the multithreading of sidekiq? Or is my index setup wrong? Has anyone seen something like this happening before? I'm baffled.

Comment: Try inserting manually in PSQL with: `INSERT INTO journal_entries (line_item_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (1, now(), now());`.  You should get `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_journal_entries_on_line_item_id"`.

Comment: insert into users? @max

Comment: Oops, `INSERT INTO journal_entries (line_item_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (1, now(), now());`.

Comment: I was copy pasting from a sandbox app.

Comment: yup just as we expect we get the error: `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_journal_entries_on_line_item_id"` @max

Comment: PostgreSQL isn't going to silently replace a value with NULL unless you have some rules or triggers telling it to; a manual INSERT fails so you don't have anything in the database that would mess things up. Multithreading shouldn't matter (as far as the database is concerned). Why does `line_item_id` even allow NULLs? How are you sure that your Ruby code isn't neglecting to set `line_item_id` in some cases?

Comment: @muistooshort ya it needs to be nullable for certain cases. I've put log statements all over the LineItem model in callbacks such as after create, save, update etc and never have any of those callbacks caught one of these instances occurring. Also in those callbacks I'm telling it to delete the rows if it catches one.